# Why * operator gave wrong result and Math.pow() correct

Tags: java, math, pow, multiplication

I am caluclating difference between two color histograms which are 3 dimension arrays:

`deltaH` is `double`.

```
int[][][] t1 = item.getCh();
                    int[][][] t2 = comparedItem.getCh();
                    for(int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++)
                        for(int j = 0; j < t1[i].length; j++)
                            for(int p = 0; p < t1[i][j].length; p++)
                                deltaH = deltaH + ((t1[i][j][p] - t2[i][j][p]) * (t1[i][j][p] - t2[i][j][p]));
```

In the result of that one above someties I got negative numbers which is mathematically impossible.
When instead using `*` I used Math.pow() method:

```
  int[][][] t1 = item.getCh();
                        int[][][] t2 = comparedItem.getCh();
                        for(int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++)
                            for(int j = 0; j < t1[i].length; j++)
                                for(int p = 0; p < t1[i][j].length; p++)
                                    deltaH = deltaH + Math.pow(t1[i][j][p] - t2[i][j][p],2);
```

I got correct results. Why is it so?

Comment: Your numbers don't fit in `int`.

Comment: @SLaks Still we have x*x >= 0 even if these numbers have no sense.

Comment: What is the type of `deltaH`?

Comment: @Szymon double. Pozdr.

Comment: Floris's answer is satisfying. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you multiply two `int`s you can get overflow. The `Math.pow` function converts its argument to double first - no risk of overflow resulting in negative numbers once you have a `double` (although you might still get overflow … but at a much larger number).

This is in essence what @Slaks 's comment was saying. I just expanded it.

**EDIT** a quick code snippet shows this is true:

```
for(ii = 0; ii >= 0; ii++) {
  jj = ii * ii;
  if(jj < 0) break;
}
System.out.printf("%d; %d\n", ii, jj);
```

prints out

```
46341; -2147479015
```